# need help in anayzing a text file using python

Tags: python

I have the text file which contains 3 columns, first column having strings, second column having integers and 3rd column having floating points like this:

```
steve   134     0.000010

Harry   133 0.000012

joanne  134 0.000022

steve   135 0.000024

joanne  133 0.000045

steve   133 0.000078

joanne  133 0.000079    

joanne  133 0.000081    

joanne  136 0.000083

steve   134 0.000085

steve   135 0.000087
```

I want output which looks like this:

```
steve   134(count=2,Time interval=0.000085-0.000010),133(count=1,Time interval=0.000078-0.000000),135(count=2,Time interval=0.000087-0.000024),136(count=0, Time interval=0.000000-0.000000)

harry   134(count=0, Time interval),133(count=1, Time interval),135(count=0, Time interval),136(count=0, Time interval)

joanne  134(count=1, Time interval),133(count=3, Time interval),135(count=0, Time interval),136(count=1, Time interval)
```

[Time intervals of harry and joanne is calculated in the same way as that of steve].

Basically, if i take steve, i have to calculate how many entries of 133,134,135,136 each steve has and in what time interval did 133,134,135,136 happen. I hope you guys get my query.

Comment: What are you having trouble with? What have you tried?

Comment: i dont know how to approach this problem. A direction would be helpful.

Comment: Are you having trouble opening the file? Have you looked at Python's [CSV Reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)? It looks like you're using a file that's tab delimited. Or are you having trouble with parsing?

Comment: Also collections.Counter and/or collections.defaultdict http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/collections.html

Comment: I think you'll need to first learn how to open the file..follow the tutorials and if you can display the file in python then your good to go, next maybe make a dict of dict, first key is the name, then the value is a dictionary with the numbers like 134 as the keys and the value is list that you keep adding the observations to.  Once you parse the entire file, its simply a matter of outputting whats in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> names = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('f.txt') as f:
...    lines = [l.split() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()]
...    for l in lines:
...      names[l[0]].append([l[1],l[2]])
>>> for i in names.iteritems():
...    print i
... 
('steve', [['134', '0.000010'], ['135', '0.000024'], ['133', '0.000078'], ['134', 
'0.000085'], ['135', '0.000087']])
('joanne', [['134', '0.000022'], ['133', '0.000045'], ['133', '0.000079'], ['133', '0.000081'], ['136', '0.000083']])
('Harry', [['133', '0.000012']])
```

Comment: The result obtained and expected results do not match. For example, steve has 133 only 1 time, but this program gave 5 times....

Comment: hi burhan, how can we get the counts like in your previous post?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid For homework cases (and this surely is one of them) when the OP does not post any code, it does not seems right to me to post a complete solution.

Comment: Which is why I left the counting and the differing of the times out @betabandido